# Looping with RDDs in Spark with Scala

Tags: scala, loops, bigdata, rdd

So I have this assignment in Spark Shell using Scala where we are given a tsv-file of ~3M tweets, and we are supposed to estimate the location of the next tweet (which is input from a text file we write) based on the Naive Bayes estimator. Such that if I write "please help me out stackoverflow", it will output the winner with the highest chance of tweeting that location, for example: "Birmingham, 0.2"

So first I take in the data from the tsv-file and do some rdd-transformations:

```
val t = sc.textFile("PATH-TO-DATASET")
val s = t.map(_.split('\t')) //
val location = s.map(x => x(4))
val locAndTweetText = s.map(x => (x(4),x(10)))
val distinctLoc = location.distinct()
```

Now what I want to do but cant figure out is: How can I loop over each location and output the fraction of that place relative to the entire dataset?

I've tried variants of:

```
for (e <- distinctLoc) {
  val a = location.filter(x => x == e).count()
  val b = a / t.count()
  println(b)
}
```

But I keep just getting errors. After this I need to do the same again for the input-words of my file for each location, but I can't do a nested for-loop when I don't even get a single one working. Anyone has any idea?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: "I keep just getting errors" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Answer (score 2):

You are working with RDDs, not arrays.  You have to treat them differently.  Specifically, you can't nest another rdd operation into each other like you are doing here.

Looks like you are trying to get the count of how many of each location.  This is accomplished using a `groupBy`, using the element itself as a key, and then counting how many elements for each key.

```
val locationCounts = location.groupBy(identity).mapValues(iter => iter.length())
```

You then are trying to calculate the ratio of those counts and the total record count.  You could get the count of `t` outside any loop or other rdd operation.

```
val totalCount = t.count()
```

Finally, iterate the `locationCounts` RDD and print the value.

```
for((location, count) <- locationCounts){
  val ratio = count / totalCount.toDouble
  println(location + ": " + ratio)
}
```

If you want to get the results in a new RDD instead of just printing them out, just use a map instead of a foreach.

```
val locationRatios = locationCounts.map{
  case (location, count) => location -> (count / totalCount.toDouble)
}
```

or use the for version

```
val locationRatios = for((location, count) <- locationCounts) 
   yield location -> (count / totalCount.toDouble)
```

Now `locationRatios` is an `RDD[(String, Double)]` containing the ratio of the total number of records for each location.

Comment: That worked well, thank you! however, Instead of printing it, I wanted to store it in a new RDD or array outside of the function, but that RDD or list does not update after the operation is over. Any idea as to go around that? Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: @OneQuestionAwayFromNirvana I've updated my answer to include that case

Comment: Thanks a million!